# How do I cure my disease?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Apparently I have Witbane, although I don't remember contracting it. Last time I got a disease, I was only informed of it because a random passerby on the road offered to cure it for me. Wandering the countryside in hopes of a benevolent priest is obviously not a reliable way to go about curing this and future diseases.

How can I cure this disease?

Comment: I saw a comment saying there are potion's, Cure potions are often found just lying around, What would happen to be the recipe for such?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Receive any blessing from any God in a Temple, and you get all diseases cured. Examples are the Shrine of Talos and the Temple of Kynareth ((Whiterun)

Comment: there are also Potion of Cure Disease, in case you want to carry a few around so you don't have to walk back to town every time a wolf bites you

Comment: how about cure disease potions?

Comment: Some shrines can be found in the "wild". They aren't just in temples but temples are probably easier to find.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the Brawny Prawn in Riften, you can buy a Cure Disease potion that'll do the job as well.

The Brawny Prawn is beside the Bee And Barb to the right of it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @britt! If you have more information to add to your answer, it would be preferable to edit your own post to include it there rather than commenting on it. The "edit" link is off to the left on your answer, next to the upvotes/downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

In the town of Riften, you can visit the Temple of Mara. Go inside the temple and activate the Shrine of Mara, in the front-center of the temple. That will cure your diseases, and people will stop telling you that you look sick.